# Change the next display date on datepicker in android

Tags: android, date, datepicker

In my application i have a requirement to display the current date on date picker and the next date after current should be the nearest sunday. Like if today is 20th may 2013, my date picker will be showing it as current date and the next date will not be the 21st may 2013 , but it will be  26th may 2013 as this is the nearest possible sunday.

Can anyone please help. any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you should use a 'NumberPicker' instead and use some String values to display a list of sundays.

Is that what you want to achieve?

```
NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(this);
picker.setMinValue(0);
picker.setMaxValue(2);
picker.setDisplayedValues( new String[] { "12th may 2013", "19th may 2013", "26th may 2013" } );
```

It's quite trivial to display dynamically all the sundays in user Locale, from a defined period, I have not my dev computer in front of me, but you should easily do it.